# One trigger per object is commonly espoused as best practice, but is that so for event triggers as well?

Tags: apex, trigger, event, bestpractice, platform-event

According to the documentation it is considered best practice to maintain a single trigger, even for Events the documentation reads:

> ... However, having multiple triggers on the same object isn’t a best practice because we can't guarantee the order of execution, so we recommend that you add only one trigger per object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_batch_resume.htm

But it seems to me less obvious that this is as important for events as it is for objects. Where an object trigger is directly tied back to a singular record in Salesforce and concurrency issues are obvious, Events don't necessarily have to be underpinned by any specific record*, nor do they even need to be contextually related to existing records at all.

It seems antithetical to the purpose of of a pub-sub to capitulate at the point of subscription and to re-couple listener logic in one place in the Org. Wouldn't it be better if all interested consumers implemented their own event listeners? There would not be a single point of failure and conflict which is a common ailment of Object triggers (granted, with patterns that help).

So to actually ask a question: Is the notion of 1 trigger 1 object (or in this case, event) still "considered best practice", or is this just a bit of mindless copy-paste from existing documentation>?

* Ignoring any semantic argument to be had about events "sort of" being objects, point is they are not persistent... ignoring any argument about temporary persistence when queuing... point is they cannot be edited in flight.

Answer (score 5):

A short answer based on my experience

- In SFDC, you can have multiple subscribers to a platform event - these could be *n* triggers, or a trigger and a process builder, or ...
- You need to think about race conditions and non-deterministic order of execution when you have more than one trigger per `xxx__e` object.  I had this very issue and changed my logic to the one trigger per `xxx__e`

So, in a decoupled system with many interested parties simply monitoring incoming `xxx__e` you can probably have multiple subsribers without issue. But with DML as the result of a `xxx__e` subscriber, more things need to be thought through to handle possible database out-of-sync situations